# Get USD to INR exchange rate dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

[image]

I'm developing a Windows application to convert USD to INR. I know how to convert by taking USD to INR exchange rate in static way, but I want the exchange rate to be available dynamically in my readonly textbox like I have kept in above image.

After searching on SO I found this solution in C but I want to do the same in C#. My aim is to get the USD to INR exchange rate in my readonly textbox dynamically each day from the web.

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate

Which method should I use in above reference to get USD to INR exchange rate dynamically?

Comment: Choose one code as the base and do the rest on it

Comment: Take a look at System.Net.WebRequest - it should do what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx.  If you run into any issues update your question with code and point out the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code piece:
Add System.IO and System.Net and System.Xml

```
WebRequest webrequest =WebRequest.Create("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
        string value = doc.InnerText;
        MessageBox.Show(value);
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Comment: I'm getting `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">49.385</double>` in my textbox but how can i get 49.385 value only in my textbox.

Comment: You should put your streams in using() blocks so they are closed even if errors occur

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add the service reference, you can also just request the page:
http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR

Comment: Do I need to signup for this service?

Answer (score 0):

Conversion Rate is the right method to call.  You can add a service method to your project.  You may have to point it to the [WSDL](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL) file.  Make one call to get the base rate and then calculate the other rate by using 1/result of the first call.