# Dynamically changing the price of an item based on the exchange rate

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server, rate

I am building a website in which I need to display the price of certain items.The price needs to be updated daily based on the exchange rate. How do I go about doing this in asp.net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311495/get-usd-to-inr-exchange-rate-dynamically-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If question is about how to get currency rates in ASP.NET, than you can use something like this:

```
    private static string GetCurrencyRate(string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
    {
        WebRequest webrequest = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency={0}&ToCurrency={1}", fromCurrency, toCurrency));
        using (WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
                    return doc.InnerText;                     
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Using:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetCurrencyRate("GBP", "USD"));
```

If thereis a problem with displaying this data in web page, than you can tell us more precise about your site, because thereis a few different methods.